# Java IllegalCastException when casting object returned from API call

Tags: java, android, casting, google-calendar-api

I am trying to integrate a public google calendar into my android application. To do this without the complicated oauth2 flow, I used a firebase cloud function to perform the API call. However, the json returned to my application has the java.lang Object type. I tried casting this to the google calendar Events type and I receive a IllegalCastException.

What I have tried:
First I tried to use gson to convert the object to a json string, then use the fromJson function to convert the string back to the Events class. This sorta worked, but I would get an error stating the argument "events.Updated" is type DateTime, but got String... I tried various methods of making sure gson was using the correct date format but in the end I tried something else.

Then I tried to use reflection to convert the object but then I found myself having to use reflection for every sub object and it was getting ugly so I stopped.

Here is what I tried for reflection:

```
Events placeholderEvents = new Events();
Class aClass = Events.class;
for (Field field : aClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    if (map.containsKey(field.getName())) {
        if (field.getType().toString().equals("class com.google.api.client.util.DateTime")) {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
            Timestamp datetime = new Timestamp(simpleDateFormat.parse((String) map.get(field.getName())).getTime());
            DateTime date = new DateTime(datetime);
            field.set(placeholderEvents, date);
        } else if (field.getType().toString().equals("interface java.util.List")) {
            ArrayList<Object> innerArray = (ArrayList<Object>) map.get(field.getName());
            List<Event> placeholderList = new ArrayList<>();
            Class secondClass = placeholderList.getClass();
            for (Object object : innerArray) {
                for (Field innerField : secondClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
                    innerField.setAccessible(true);
                    if (innerArray.contains(innerField.getName())) {
                        Log.i("innerfield", "" + innerArray.get(innerArray.indexOf(innerField.getName())));
                        innerField.set(placeholderList, innerArray.get(innerArray.indexOf(innerField.getName())));
                    }
                }
            }
            field.set(placeholderEvents, placeholderList);
        } else {
            field.set(placeholderEvents, map.get(field.getName()));
        }
    }
}
return placeholderEvents;
```

So my question is, how can I cast an Object of which I know the type of its contents at compile time to its type so that I can access the type specific functions? I know it is supposed to be of type Events, but I cannot cast it from Object.

Is something like this possible?

```
Object obj = task.getResult().getData();
Events events = (Events) obj;
```

Comment: There are libraries like GSON and Jackson that do what you want-  convert JSON directly into objects

Comment: I noted in my question that I did use gson, however I had trouble when it came to parsing datetimes that were a part of the Events class. I tried using Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'") .create(); however it seems to not be able to deserialize the date despite that. Is there another way to use gson to convert this object? Or could you go more in depth with converting JSON directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not cast it directly.

```
Object obj = task.getResult().getData();
Events events = (Events) obj;
```

like that.
solution is

1. You manually parse JSONObject and use getters and setters to set
   properties of Event Object. If you do not have getter and setter, you need to use reflaction of JAVA.
2. You create your own class with annotations of Gson library than
   You can convert JSONObject to Your Class.

Comment: I can see how annotations could help with parsing the dates... could you provide more detail on how to convert the JSON Object to Events? Thank you for your help

Comment: visit: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and select source JSON and Anotation style GSON and hit preview button. dont forget to add GSON library to your project

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
((Events)obj).eventFunction();
```

You just need to make sure the whole cast is in the brackets

Comment: Unfortunately it results in the same     java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events
error